# Encoding/providing string & integer values in sqarql GET requests

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I have a sparql query with a `FILTER` statement as follows:

```
FILTER ((?dayOfWeek = ?day) && (?start >= ?startTime) && (?finish <= ?finishTime))
```

I know that this query runs correctly if I replace with literal values and execute on snorql:

```
FILTER ((?dayOfWeek = "Wed") && (?start >= 720) && (?finish <= 820))
```

I want to provide the values via a GET request instead, so something like:

```
...sparql?query=<query>&day=Wed&startTime=720&finishTime=820
```

However, the above request doesn't work (it returns an empty data set).  I've tried specifying the types of `startTime` and `finishTime`, ie

```
...sparql?query=<query>&day=Wed&startTime=720&startTime_type=integer&finishTime=820&finishTime_type=integer
```

but this doesn't fix the issue.

Providing the literal values that work on snorql in the query string also results in an empty dataset, which is really puzzling me.

I assume that I must either be providing the values in the wrong way, or encoding them incorrectly.  The query string itself has been percent escaped (character set: `!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the SPARQL protocol, the usage is

```
...sparql?query=PREFIX .. SELECT...
```

i.e. a complete SPARQL query (encoded for being in a URL).

Comment: I was sending a complete query (I'm not that silly!), I just cut it down for the purposes of this post.  It turned out that the issue was that one of my parameters was specified with the full namespace in a way that the sparql engine did not support.